# Connecting to 2 VPNs in parallel

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

For my workflow I need to use two VPNs.

At the moment I have to alternate between then with OpenVPN connect. That cripples my productivity since I can't do a job that depends on VPN 1 if a process that uses VPN 2 is running (like a heavy db query).

Is there anyway to run both of them simultaneously? Someway to route requests to the correct network by subnet or domain? Maybe using a 3rd VPN running locally on my PC?

Comment: You havnt specified where you are running this or your IS setup but, provided the IP addresses to be reached through the VPN are in different ranges it is entirely practical to set up multiple openVPN clients at one time (at least this is so on my routers using dd-wrt and a bit of hacking, and on my Linux desktop)

Comment: I've control only of my local machine, it`s a Windows box since I need to use Excel.
Using two clients (OpenVPN Connect and OpenVPN GUI) worked for a while but have stopped after I've formatted the machine.